# Open SSL 1.1 X compile and create dll on window

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, openssl, window

I am compiling openssl-1.1.0h version on Window 7 64 bit machine.
I have followed below steps:

1. Downloaded the source code from open ssl website
   https://www.openssl.org/source/
2. Installed Visual Studio 2015 and required Perl environment.
3. perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=custom-dir --openssldir=custom-dir no-asm shared
4. nmake
5. namke test
6. nmake install

I am able to successfully compile the source code, but it has created libcrypto.lib and libssl.lib files under lib folder. How can I create dll instead of libs?

Comment: They would have got created already in bin folder

Comment: DLL (libssl-1_1-x64,libcrypto-1_1-x64) are create in bin folder but not in lib folder. I want to link my code to .dll instead of .lib, as the use of .lib generally increase the .exe size. The dll created in the bin folder are used at runtime but can't link my code to these dll  at compile time.